# Verificar se chamada veio de API (.Net Core) ou MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tenho algumas aplicações que precisam compartilhar o mesmo Repositório (Class Library).

O projeto do Repositório está criado e funcionando, com aplicações MVC. O problema é que busca a connection string utilizando ConfigurationManager, diretamente no repositório.

Preciso criar uma API em .Net Core e a configuração da API não é acessada pelo ConfigurationManager. Então, quando a chamada é feita, dá erro ao acessar o ConfigurationManager.

Existe uma maneira de procurar a connection string via IConfiguration ou ConfigurationManager, dependendo da origem da chamada, e sem ter que passar o IConfiguration da controller pro repositório?

Comment: Os dois são `Aspnet Core`? e as duas aplicações estão no mesmo `Project`?

Comment: Considerou a ideia de passar a connection string por parâmetro na hora de instanciar o repositório? Assim você deixa o código menos acoplado :)

Comment: Algumas aplicações são MVC (.Net Framework) e a nova API é Aspnet Core.
Eu já tenho muitas chamadas pra esses repositórios e não gostaria de alterar todas. Se existir uma maneira de passar por isso, sem precisar alterar a assinatura dos métodos, seria melhor.

Comment: Existe muita bobeira no mercado dividindo todo o projeto principalmente aqueles que ficam impondo DDD, mas, a camada de banco de dados e sua conexão precisam ser independentes do projeto e no projeto você passar a conectividade. `NetFramework` e `NetCore` tem peculiaridades diferentes mas, isso talvez possa ser resolvido com uma classe onde a mesma busque a conexão dependendo do projeto. Você precisa exemplificar como está hoje os dois projetos para ter uma ideia real do problema

Comment: @VirgilioNovic então, eu tenho classes como UsuarioRepository, por exemplo, que precisam ser acessadas por projetos dos dois tipos. Só que no repositório, eu utilizo simplesmente: public static string ConnectionString => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;

Comment: NetFramework é qual versão?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Framework: 4.6.1 e Core: 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proponha para o seu código, um pacote que tem em seu código particularidades sendo que a versão do projeto faz referencia ao seu modelo atual dos seus dois projetos `ASPNETFULL` e `ASPNETCORE` da seguinte forma:

Crie uma Classe Library e depois edite o seu arquivo `.csproj` e no conteúdo altere para:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">  
  <PropertyGroup>
      <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.9</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworks>net46;net461;net47;netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.1;netcoreapp2.2</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net46'">    
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net461'">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />    
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net47'">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp2.1'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp2.2'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>  
</Project>
```

isso fará com que essa `Library` seja compatível com os dois projetos e o código principal onde vai buscar as configurações de conexão é:

```
namespace Library
{
    public class FindConnection
    {
#if NET46 || NET461 || NET47 || NETSTANDARD2_0
        public System.Guid FullId { get; } = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        public static string StringConnection
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["minhaconnection"].ToString();
            }
        }
#endif
#if NETCOREAPP2_1 || NETCOREAPP2_2
        public System.Guid CoreId { get; } = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        public FindConnection (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            StringConnection = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:minhaconnection").Value;
        }
        public string StringConnection { get; }
#endif
    }
}
```

nesse código vai acontecer uma ***compilação condicional*** e por isso o código vai caber nos dois projetos e claro cada um com sua particularidade.

Para utilizar essa `Library` adicione referencia nos seus projetos e no `ASPNETFULL` utilize da seguinte forma:

```
string stringConnection = FindConnection.StringConnection;
```

e no projeto `ASPNETCORE` utilize com ***injeção de dependência*** configurando:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<FindConnection>(); // aqui
    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

e no seu `controller` por exemplo:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public FindConnection FindConnection { get; }

    public HomeController(FindConnection findConnection)
    {
        FindConnection = findConnection;
    }
```

Eu faria mais ainda na sua camada Repositório criaria um construtor com essa classe e faria tudo por ***injeção de dependência*** facilidade encontrada no **ASPNETCORE**.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa instalar através o Nuget o ConfigurationManager no ASP.NET Core (considerando que esteja usando o 2.0, anterior a isso não tem suporte):

```
Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version 4.5.0
```

Agora crie o app.config com as configurações:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="minhaconnection" connectionString="server=localhost;database=legacy" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Por fim, acesse normalmente:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["minhaconnection"].ConnectionString
```